# Asynchronous operations for a repository to save new data to database

Tags: c#, csv, asynchronous

I have a class called Repository which handles a CSV file and creates Objects from parsed values.

There is are two list properties in this class:

```
public static List<Product> ProductsList { get; set; }
public static List<Category> CategoriesList { get; set; }
```

There is a method in the Repository class which parses a posted CSV file to create a list of products and categories which get assigned to `ProductsList` and `CategoriesList` respectively inside the method.

```
public static void CSVToList(HttpPostedFileBase CSVFile){}
```

Then there is another method in this class which saves the products and categories into the dbContext.Both of these methods are called from outside the Repository class in the Controller.

```
public static void SaveProducts()
        {
            foreach(var item in ProductsList)
            {
                db.Products.Add(item);
            }

            foreach(var item in CategoriesList)
            {
                db.Categories.Add(item);
            }

            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
```

When I run the application and send a post request with a CSV file, I get this error:

> An asynchronous operation cannot be started at this time. Asynchronous operations may only be started within an asynchronous handler or module or during certain events in the Page lifecycle. If this exception occurred while executing a Page, ensure that the Page is marked <%@ Page Async="true" %>. This exception may also indicate an attempt to call an "async void" method, which is generally unsupported within ASP.NET request processing. Instead, the asynchronous method should return a Task, and the caller should await it.

```
Source Error: 


Line 348:            {
Line 349:                Repository.CSVToList(viewModel.CSVFile);
Line 350:                Repository.SaveProducts();
Line 351:
Line 352:                return RedirectToAction("Index", new { ManageMessageId.DataImportSuccess });

Source File: C:\src\smokindonut\Valueville\ValueVille\Controllers\ManageController.cs    Line: 350
```

I have tried to make the controller method be an asynchronous Task with the caller to the repository save method await:

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> AddCSVData(){

       await Repository.SaveProducts();
    }
```

I have also tried to make the SaveProducts() method be an asynchronous task also, but it keeps making the method name start with "async" - each time giving the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to changed the signature of  your function

```
public static void SaveProducts()
```

To

```
public async Task SaveProducts()
```

Your calling function then needs have a signature with async Task and call the save function like this:

```
Task saveTask = SaveProducts();
//do some logic
await saveTask;
```

Comment: I have done that and now I get an error stating "Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details" on the same line as the code: await db.SaveChangesAsync();
.